# Netbeans isn't recognizing igraph functions

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, build, igraph

Currently I'm trying to compile a very basic program in c++ using the igraph library (which can be found here: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ch03s01.html), but it doesn't recognize the functions to create and destroy graphs.

I've specified the path where igraph.h is, and it recognizes the header file fine, but when I try to build it (using Netbean's generated makefile), I get the following:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/igraphtest
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/local/lib -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-                 MacOSX/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/igraphtest build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o  
Undefined symbols:
  "_igraph_erdos_renyi_game", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_igraph_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_igraph_diameter", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/igraphtest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the location of the header file is not enough; you must also add the directory containing the igraph library itself (i.e. the file `libigraph.so` or `libigraph.dylib` if you are on Mac OS X) to the library path and ask the compiler to link to the igraph library by adding `-ligraph` to the command line options. I don't know how to do these in Netbeans, but these are the things that your compiler output is missing.

Comment: I think you're right.  I was trying to use NetBeans's generated Makefile, but after writing my own with all the things you mentioned it worked.